# Image doesn't show up in the edit form in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have entity, edit form and a controller. The entity include a string holding the path to an image. When I render the Edit form the image file upload is always empty, even if the article have image. How can I fix this?

```
/**
* @var string
* @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=500)
*/
private $image;
```

--

```
/**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @Route("admin/article/edit/{id}", name="admin_article_edit", requirements={"id": "\d+"})
     */
    public function editArticleAction(Request $request, int $id)
    {

        $article = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Article::class)->find($id);

        $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // Upload picture logic
            $oldPicture = $article->getImage();
            $imagePath = 'images/articles/';
            $uploadService = $this->get('picture_upload');
            $uploadService->uploadPicture($article, $oldPicture, $imagePath);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($article);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('article_view', array('id' => $article->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('article/add.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

--

```
$builder
->add("Title", TextType::class)
->add('Content', TextareaType::class)
->add("Image", FileType::class, array('data_class' => null));
```

Comment: this question is not clear, please explain "When I render the Edit form the image file upload is always empty, even if the article have image. ". What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is normal behavior

If you want to show the picture have a look at [How to Create a Form Type Extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html)

The example there is what you want!

Answer (score 0):

Just go through this code. This may give you an idea.

```
public function editArticleAction(Request $request, int $id)
    {
    $article = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Article::class)->find($id);

    $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // Upload picture logic

        $oldPicture = $article->getImage();
        $imagefile = $form['image']->getData();
        $imagePath = 'images/articles/';

        if(!empty($imagefile)) {

            // code for uploading new image
           ..............
           ..............

        }
        else {
              if(!empty($oldPicture)) {

                  // keep the existing one
                  ..............
                  ..............
                 // $article->setImage($oldPicture);
                  ..............
                }
        }


        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();

        .........
        .........
```